# Mongoose embedded document query returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema :

```
_schema : {

Prize : new Schema({
        prizeName : { type : String },
        thumbnailImage : [ String ],
        detailImage : [ String ],
        prizeCategory : [ {type : String, index : true } ],
        prizeDescription : { type : String },
        prizePrice : { type : Number, required : true }
    }),

Game : new Schema ({
        roomName : { type : String, required : true },
        openTime : { type : Date },
        closeTime : { type : Date },
        minPlayers : { type : Number },
        maxPlayers : { type : Number, required : true },
        numberOfPlayers : { type : Number },
        winner : { userId : { type : ObjectId, index : true, ref : 'User'} },
        prize : [ this.Prize ],
        tag : [ { type : String, index : true } ],
        status : { type : Number, index : true },
        businessType : { type : Number, required : true, index : true },
        mallId : { type : ObjectId, ref : 'Mall' },
        registeredPlayers : { type : ObjectId, ref : 'User' } 
    }),

Schedule : new Schema ({
        _id : ObjectId,
        time : { type : Date, index : true },
        game : [ this.Game ]
    }),

}
```

However when I try to query the game embedded document the object is always null.  I'm querying like so:

```
var Schedule = mongoose.model('Schedule', this._schema.Schedule);

Schedule.findById({'game._id' : req.params._id}).exec(function(err,gameDetail){...});
```

Am I doing anything wrong when I declare the schema and models?  I have seen numerous examples where people appear to be doing exactly what I'm trying.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still not having any luck with this.  I want to add that I'm using Mongoose 3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mongoose Model's [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findById) method is used to find the instance of that Model with the `_id` that's supplied as the first parameter to the method.  So `Schedule.findById` returns `Schedule` instances, not individual `Game` instances.  `Schedule.findOne({'game._id' : req.params._id}, ...` will get you the `Schedule` instance *containing* the `Game` with that id, but if you need to query for `Game` instances by id, you should be keeping them in a separate collection instead of embedding them in `Schedule`.

Comment: Thanks Johnny I actually moved Games to another collection.  And this has solved the problems I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, my first guess is actually that your `findById` isn't structured quite right.

First, you're using the value `req.params._id` to get the id. Most of the code examples I have seen, and my code, uses `:id` in the router (`app.get('/schedules/:id')`), which would actually mean the ID you're looking for is stored in `req.params.id`. You'll have to check that in your code.

Secondly, to my understanding, findById is only useful for finding, in this case, a Schedule by that ID. Try using just a normal find.

Last thought: you're missing a closing curly bracket at the end of `{'game._id' : req.params._id}`.

Hopefully something in that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have written :_id in my routes and I'm checking the value is correct with a console.log().  I will try to a find and see how that goes.